# Sorting list neglecting 0 when sorting is added in code

Tags: android, list, sorting

I am trying to sort a list of model class with respect to the exercise name which is listed below :

> Exercise 6,  Exercise 3, Exercise 02, Exercise 01

After adding the Sorting code the list data looks like this

> Exercise 3, Exercise 6,  Exercise 01, Exercise 02

Result needed is

> Exercise 01, Exercise 02, Exercise 3, Exercise 6

Below is the code used for Sorting list data

```
Collections.sort(exerciseList, new Comparator<Exercise>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Exercise exercise, Exercise exercise1) {
        return exercise.getExercise().compareTo(exercise1.getExercise());
    }
});
```

Any help is appreciable Thanks in advance.

Comment: Parse your name string and extra the integer part then use integer to compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a custom comparator to solve the purpose.

```
Collections.sort(keyList, new Comparator<String>()
{
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2)
    {
        s1 = s1.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "" );
        s2 = s2.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "" );
        Integer val1 = Integer.parseInt(s1);
        Integer val2 = Integer.parseInt(s2);
        return val1.compareTo(val2);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I need to make the Sorting global as the String exercise can also be appended with something else